# GraphQL code generation using Typescript loader

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

How can I use a typescript loader for `graphql-codegen`? I need to build my graphql schema dynamically, therefore I have to load it from a typescript file.

Here are the files I'm using:

**codegen.yaml**

```yaml
generates:
  src/generated/auth-resolvers.types.ts:
    schema: 
      - authTypeDefs:
        loader: ./src/graphql/auth.typedefs.ts
    config:
      useIndexSignature: true
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
require:
  - ts-node/register
  - tsconfig-paths/register
```

**auth.typedefs.ts**

```js
import { Permission } from "@src/generated/model.types";
import { gql } from "apollo-server";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";

let permFields = "";
for (const perm in Permission) {
  permFields += `  ${perm}: PermissionDomains\n`;
}

export default gql`
type JsonType {
  json: Json
}

type BooleanType {
  boolean: Boolean
}

union PermissionOperationDomain = JsonType | BooleanType

type SecurityDomain {
  read: PermissionOperationDomain,
  write: PermissionOperationDomain,
  update: PermissionOperationDomain,
  delete: PermissionOperationDomain
}

type SecurityDomains {
  domains: [SecurityDomain!]
}

union PermissionDomains = SecurityDomains | BooleanType

extend type Query {
  getPermissions(userId: ID!): SecurityContext
}

type SecurityContext {
${permFields}}
`;
```

To run the code generation, I have this npm script:

```bash
> graphql-codegen -r ts-node/register
```

But I keep on getting the error:

```
  ✖ src/generated/auth-resolvers.types.ts
    Failed to load schema from authTypeDefs,loader:

        Cannot read properties of null (reading 'loader')
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'loader')
```